# Trying to check if the number of lines is the same; am I using izip correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I know that `izip` can read two files at a time, but I don't know how to iterate over the two files at the same time (or if it is rational to do that). Here is my first step on the code that should read the docs line by line and return whether the docs have the same amount of lines:

```
from sys import argv  
import itertools  
a = 0   
b = 0  
doc1 = open(argv[1],"r")  
doc2 = open(argv[2],"r")  
for lineA,lineB in itertools.izip(doc1,doc2):  
    a = a + 1    
    b = b + 1    
if a/b == 1:  
    print "equal number of lines in docs"  
else:  
    print "docs with different number of lines"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example to demonstrate why that won't work:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = range(10)
>>> zip(a, b)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]  # ...is that it?
```

`zip` and `itertools.izip` truncate whichever iterable is longest, so you'll *always conclude that the two files are the same length*.

Instead, use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), which won't truncate the longer file:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> list(izip_longest(a, b))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (None, 5), (None, 6), (None, 7), (None, 8), (None, 9)]
                                        # ^ default fillvalue
```

Now you can check e.g. `if lineA is None:` to detect when a file has run out.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped, but since I'm new to python , could you also help me on how to make sure I'm going to assign each variable a,b to to each line on both docs so that i can compare them? The way I did is not actually working...

Comment: @d_Berl ...what? You're currently naming each line `lineA` and `lineB`, `a` and `b` are the counters (which you don't really need, if all you care about is whether or not they're the same length).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can count the number of `'\n'` like this:

```
from sys import argv  

with open(argv[1],"r") as f1, open(argv[2],"r") as f2:
    if f1.read().count('\n') == f2.read().count('\n'):
        print "equal number of lines in docs" 
    else:
        print "docs with different number of lines"
```